# php variable ignores boolean? Button keeps getting on table even if it's not allowed to

Tags: php

```
$button = $button == TRUE ? "<span class='button_join'>Join</span>" : "";
```

Basically, if `button = TRUE`, then show up the button.
But the buttons is always showing when I have `$button == TRUE ?` on, but I never see it getting true anywhere?

Mysql results showing for 2 rows "In Progress", and for 1 row "Available".

But the problem is, that the button shows for every row, Ill post a picture so you will know what I am talking about:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/4ed23f9793c6f69812d6140f64cea2a2.png))</sub>

What's wrong?

This is the code:

```
            while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                if (!Ping::remote($row['server_ip'], $row['server_port']))
                {
                    $status = "Offline";
                }
                else
                {
                    $status = $row['server_status'];
                }

                if ($status != "In Progress" || $status != "Offline" || $status != "Full" || $status == "Available")
                {
                    $joinButton = TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    $joinButton = FALSE;
                }

                Template::drawTableRow (
                    $row['server_name'], 
                    $row['server_players'], 
                    $row['server_map'], 
                    $row['server_status'],
                    $joinButton
                );

            }
```

`drawTableRow`:

```
    public static function drawTableRow($name, $players, $map, $status, $button)
    {

        $button = $button == TRUE ? "<span class='button_join'>Join</span>" : "";

        $status = $status == "Full" || $status == "In Progress" || $status == "Offline" ? "<span class='status_error'>".$status."</span>" : "<span class='status_success'>".$status."</span>";

        echo
        '
            <tr>
                <td>
                    '.$name.'
                </td>
                <td>
                    '.$players.'
                </td>
                <td>
                    '.$map.'
                </td>
                <td>
                    '.$status.'
                </td>
                <td>
                    '.$button.'
                </td>                   
            </tr>
        ';
    }
```

What's wrong there?

Comment: May I strongly advice you to use different variables, this code will be a nightmare to debug in a few weeks. I was thinking something like  `$buttonHtml = $button === TRUE ? "<span class='button_join'>Join</span>" : "";`

Comment: Yeah sure, I was just checking to be honest, cause i've never done (IF) ? RESULT : other result statements so yeah. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not empty sting is still == TRUE, so to make button only show for TRUE you must use === to use strict comprising. To put it simply, just do this:

```
$button = ($button === TRUE) ? "<span class='button_join'>Join</span>" : "";
```

Yes the problem is here, this will always give you TRUE:

```
if ($status != "In Progress" || $status != "Offline" || $status != "Full" || $status == "Available")
```

You probably wanted to do this :)

```
if (($status != "In Progress" && $status != "Offline" && $status != "Full") || $status == "Available")
```

Comment: Same problem with this one.

Comment: Yes, I just saw this one, maybe you sould look into it better, is qute easy to get TRUE here: if ($status != "In Progress" || $status != "Offline" || $status != "Full" || $status == "Available")

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis:

```
$button = ($button == TRUE) ? "<span class='button_join'>Join</span>" : "";
```

Comment: I am having the same problem though at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

A non-empty string in PHP is equal to Boolean true, and you're using the same variable to hold both your HTML snippet (a non-empty string) and a Boolean indicating whether to show it, so as soon as the condition evaluates true once, it will continue to do so forever after. Store your Boolean in a differently named variable, and the problem ceases to exist. You're also well advised to parenthesize defensively when using the ternary operator, so that you can tell at a glance which value will eventually be returned, as in this example:

```
$button = (($button_visible == TRUE) ? "<span class='button_join'>Join</span>" : "");
```

Update: Well, if that doesn't work, why not try this?

```
public static function drawTableRow($name, $players, $map, $status, $showJoinButton)
{

    $button = '';
    if ($showJoinButton) {
        $button = "<span class='button_join'>Join</span>";
    };

    $status = $status == "Full" || $status == "In Progress" || $status == "Offline" ? "<span class='status_error'>".$status."</span>" : "<span class='status_success'>".$status."</span>";

    echo
    '
        <tr>
            <td>
                '.$name.'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$players.'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$map.'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$status.'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$button.'
            </td>                   
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

If that doesn't behave the way you want it to, then what's happening is that wrong values are getting passed to `drawTableRow()`, not that they're being mishandled once there.

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded Updated answer to reflect an approach that doesn't get overly clever with the ternary operator.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I will try converting them to ints, and try to be like if == 1, then...

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded If you like, but I'd first examine what's getting passed to `drawTableRow()`. In any case, good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

***Problem was:***

First of all, I used flags ( `||` ), secondary:

The IP i've used in the database, was not reachable, therefore it always end up being "Offline".

Hence when I changed all `||` to `&&` and then added a reachable IP, it worked.